# How do I check the value of the background color in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

This code will display one table cell. When I click the table cell, the background color alerts rgb(173,216,230), but I want to check against that color and if it is that color, then alert that it worked. My check always fails. Anyone know how to solve the problem?

```
    <html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

    $("td").click(function(){
        alert($(this).css('background-color'));
        if ($(this).css('background-color') === 'rgb(173,216,230)') alert("matched");

    });
});
</script>

<style> 

button{color: black}
button:hover{background-color: lightblue}
td{color: black;width:30px; height:30px;text-align:center;}
td:hover{background-color: lightblue}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, td, th {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: yellow;
}
</style>

</head>
<body style='padding-left: 1cm;'>

<table>
<tr>
<td>test</td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `rgb(173, 216, 230)` missing spaces. You should use data-attributes or something similar. Trying to parse css properties in javascript is not fun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing spaces:

```
background-color:rgb(173, 216, 230);


if($(this).css('background-color') == 'rgb(173, 216, 230)') {
    alert("matched");
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9f5jwxpo/